# Bizzarre bug in IE7 (surprise)

Tags: internet-explorer-7

On [this url](http://centralpa.floorcoveringsinternational.com/), the text below the Flash piece in the footer will sometimes disappear in IE7, if you slowly scroll up and down a few times. It is difficult to reproduce, but it seems to be related to the flash covering up part of the window and then not refreshing after it's gone. Diffifult to explain, but any help would be great.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue - it only occurs on the middle line of text.  Your markup looks clean. I agree with Rakesh, looks like Peekaboo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding:

```
html { background : url(null) fixed no-repeat; }
```

Don't ask >.<

Comment: I never knew null was a valid argument to the url() value. Anyhow, IE is like the hell on web!

Answer (score 3):

Can't check your URL since I'm on a mobile device right now, but on reading your description, it sounds like a classic case of the 'Peekaboo bug' in IE. Look it up on google; there are pretty solid solutions in place.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that if you minimize the page and restore it fixes the glitch. I would assume its an I.E. graphic flaw and not related to your site.